# C #2140: Type error in argument 1 to 'scanf'; expected 'const char * restrict' but found 'int'

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using Pelles compiler for windows.
I got two errors

```
#2168: Operands of '&' have incompatible types 'char *' and 'char *'.
#2140: Type error in argument 1 to 'scanf'; expected 'const char * restrict' but found 'int'.
```

My code looks like

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    static char herp[20];

    int main()
    {
         int a;
         a = 2;
         printf("Some random number %d\n" ,a);
         scanf("Input: %c" &herp);
         getchar();
         return 0;
    }
```

It seems like it's having alot of problems with scanf so i'm not sure why. I am very new to C and enjoy it alot so far. The help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a comma between the string and the second argument in `scanf`.

Comment: Which book are you reading?

Comment: I am just canning through many tutorials on the internet. One of the tutorials I enjoy following is http://www.cprogramming.com

Comment: I've yet to see a single "tutorial" for C online that was not riddled with errors.  I think this is because the only people that are motivated enough to try and write one are all newbies that don't know the difference between 'correct' and 'it compiles'.

Comment: @RandyHoward typically, they want to prove to the world that they are important because they know something, but they can't be bothered becoming a professor, hence my next comment:

Comment: @John books written by professors are more useful because the professors have more money to spend on proofreading an publishing, have been trained to teach people and have a reputation to keep. Professors aren't *nobodies*. Tutorial authors *are nobodies*. Make the smarter choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("Input: %c" &herp);
```

missing a comma:

```
scanf("Input: %c", &herp);
```

Since `herp` is a character array, you should specify what character you want to write into, e.g.

```
scanf("Input: %c", &herp[0]); // to write to the first character.
```

If you were inputting a string, you'd leave off the `&`:

```
scanf("Input: %s", herp);
```

Comment: Thank you I don't know why I did not catch that but why am I still getting this error? #2234: Argument 2 to 'scanf' does not match the format string; expected 'char *' but found 'char (*)[20]'.

Comment: @John Just change it to `scanf("Input: %c", herp);` Technically it is the same as `&herp` but compiler will complain.

Comment: @Armin: They are not the same; `herp` is `char *`, and `&herp` is `char (*)[20]`. The latter is an array type; `herp + 1` and `&herp + 1` point to very different places.

Comment: @Armin I did change it to that. It's just giving me a warning is all and it wont compile if i'm still getting the warning.

Comment: @nneonneo Yes they *herp + 1 and &herp + 1* do , but i was talking about `herp` and `&herp` and they point to the same space.

Comment: Both `"%s"` and `"%c"` require a `char*` argument, though they do different things with it. You could use either `herp` or `&herp[0]` as the argument in either case -- but `herp` is clearer for `"%s"`. If you're scanning a single `char`, why not just use a single `char` object rather than an array?

Comment: @John: It's giving you a warning? What does the warning say?

Comment: @Keith #2234: Argument 2 to 'scanf' does not match the format string; expected 'char ' but found 'char ()[20]' It was that but the whole array situation using scanf("Input: %c", &herp[0]); fixed it. I appreciate the help guys :)

Comment: @armin True, but the two different pointer types aren't required to have the same representations. Passing &herp is UB because scanf expects a pointer to char, not a pointer to array of 20 char.

Comment: @John: When copy-and-pasting an error message, you should use backticks to mark the message as code. The `*` characters seem to have been eaten.